# Site can't be Reached

Tags: dns, wordpress

I was just working hard on my Wordpress website. Its URL is http://blogani.com/

I logged off for days to do some work at home, and I leave to work on my website.

After 2 or 3 days when I come to start work again my website was not working. It showed this error:

**This site can’t be reached:**

**blogani.com’s server DNS address could not be found.ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**

And also `blogani.com/wp-admin` is not working.

I am in huge problem.I do backups but it doesn't work. What could be happening?

Comment: The site works for me, it does appear to be a completely blank WordPress site with no custom content.

Comment: Yes the site is up and the wp-admin is also working.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with the `DNS server`, not with your website. Basically, when you are trying to resolve `blogani.com`, there's no server resolving that domain.

Possible reason is that the server hosting your domain is down, so you are not able to connect to your site as the ip address is unknown.